# Setting timeoutInterval on Alamofire DataRequest

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlrequest

I'm making a custom class that takes an Alamofire `DataRequest` in it's initializer. Now I want to add a timeoutInterval to it, but I'm getting the compiling error

> Value of type 'DataRequest' has no member 'timeoutInterval'

Here is the code:

```
init(request: DataRequest, timeoutInterval: Double = 10) {
    request.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval // <- compile error here
    self.request = request
}
```

Obviously Alamofire `DataRequest` doesn't have that property. But is there any other way to specify the timeout to a request in this way (without using a SessionManager preferable)? `URLRequest` has it, so it should be possible somehow, but I cannot figure out how.

I know that this question has been asked before here on Stack Overflow, but I cannot find any answer that fits this situation.

Comment: Currently using Alamofire 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Alamofire 5.1 we've added a `requestModifier` parameter to the top level `request` methods that gives you access to the `URLRequest` that will be performed.

In Alamofire 4 you have a few, less elegant options. One straightforward way to set it is to use a `RequestAdapter` that will set it as part of the request pipeline. Another, more involved option, is to move from the top level `request` method that takes individual parameters, such as headers, to the API that takes a `URLRequestConvertible` value. That way you have full control over the `URLRequest`s that are performed by Alamofire on your behalf.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit how to use the `RequestAdaptor`, because I get `'adapt' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level`-error when I try this: `let urlRequest = try request.request?.adapt(using: MyRequestAdapter())`

Comment: I upgraded to Alamofire 5.1, then it all became much simpler, thanks.